# Unable to create folders on sharepoint, unable to change metadata in files either

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Our SharePoint 2016 site has been contructed by myself over a month period. 
It was a challenge but I felt it looks and works great. However there is an issue which could spell disaster if I don't fix it.

It works like this. We have a "Vault" or single document library with folders. Total of about 50 folders with 1000 files overall.
I use a content query webpart on various pages to bring in certain documents based on data in columns. This works great, or rather it did.

Today I noticed that I was unable to modify any metadata on any file. I tried in the properties dialogue and then the quick edit. Things just time out.
So I thought it could be a workflow, none were running. Out of desperation I tried to delete all workflows (only 3), but I am unable to delete them. No error message is given, they just won't delete, in designer or SharePoint.

So I thought, maybe make a new doc lib and move all the stuff there. But I noticed I am unable to make any folders. If I try it just stays there. No folder appears. Then I get Unexpected response from server.
If I cancel out the folder then appears. I have no idea what is happening. It was working fine until yesterday and I have done nothing but add more files to the "Vault" and put some CEWP on some pages.

I am supposed to launch this site to potentially 10 thousand people next week and in its current state, it doesn't work.

Notes: I have no access to the server nor can I use powershell. The site collection was made for us by our organisation HQ. I have full control, site collection admin rights.

Comment: Check available drive space on all machines in your farm especially SQL server box and search indexing server.

Comment: If you don't have access to do it yourself, put in a request to have the SharePoint farm rebooted.  Like most tech problems, that fixes it half the time.

Comment: Check with your server admins to see if any new patches or updates where applied.  Sometimes the SharePoint configuration wizard has to be run on the server after updates or service packs are installed.

Comment: @willman I will put a request in on those things Monday if this doesn't resolve itself.
However, I did notice something. Any document library with site columns which I have added to the search schema, I can't change metadata or add folders.

But if I make a normal library with just default columns, I can add folders without any issues.

Comment: Also, I just made a new fresh library. I can add folders. So I added the site columns and I can still make folders. So I'm stumped.

Comment: Sure someone didn't change permissions on you?

Comment: There is an 'Advanced Setting' in library settings to disable/enable folder creation, but even turned off wouldn't affect your ability to change metadata.

Comment: I've checked permissions. All normal. It seems you are correct in the fact I will have to get them to have a look into it. It's beyond my powers.